# How to apply filter to specific datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Is it possible to apply a certain filter to only one datatable?
I have the following filter function that I am applying on document ready, I don't know if this is proper procedure, but as a side effect all dataTables will be affected by the filter. I would Like to affect only the $('#productTable'), but this selector appears to not have the desired effect.

```
//Filter Function in Stock 
//$('#productTable').
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var checked = $('#instock').is(':checked');
    var qntStock = 1; 
    var stockCol = 3; 

    if (!checked) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checked && aData[stockCol] > qntStock) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
 });
```

Is it possible to apply a filter only to a particular table? How do I accomplish this?

EDIT:

dataTable initialization:

```
var oTable = $('#productTable').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "sClass": "my_class", 
            "aTargets": [4]
            }],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $("td.my_class").editable(function(value, settings) 
            { 
                return(value);
            }, 
            {
                indicator : 'Save...',
                tooltip   : 'Click to Edit...'
            }
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using an ajax source, or is it part of the html/array etc.. ?

Comment: Data is loaded from web sql local to the browser

Comment: Could you add the code you use to initialize the datatables?

Comment: Sure it's added. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Last thing, I promise :) Do you call that function (fnFiltering.push) anywhere in your code? If so just paste that chunk :D

Comment: You could specify the table when you call the function. Like `oTable.afnFiltering.push()` try that and see if it helps.

Comment: it doesn't because oTable is used to reference multiple tables depending on the function being used... perhaps I have to change that behavior... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: YES! Name each table differently. like oTable1 oTable2 etc. I thought you might be calling the generic function that's why i recommended to use oTable. Change the names and try.

Comment: Unfortunatly the code is not originally mine and the developer did use the same variable oTable for all tables :rolleyes:

Comment: If all your tables are supposed to behave the same, i guess that would work. But i don't think that is a good idea.. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could create an array of tables to have the filter - then in your filter check if the current table is present in that array ... something like :

```
// setup an array of the ids of tables that should be allowed
var allowFilter = ['productTable'];

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {

    // check if current table is part of the allow list
    if ( $.inArray( oSettings.nTable.getAttribute('id'), allowFilter ) == -1 )
    {
       // if not table should be ignored
       return true;
    }
    var checked = $('#instock').is(':checked');
    var qntStock = 1; 
    var stockCol = 3; 

    if (!checked) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checked && aData[stockCol] > qntStock) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I used a simpler version since I want to filter only one table but this will work in a more genric way.

Comment: this didn't work for me, `oSettings.nTable` needs to be `oSettings.nTable.getAttribute('id')`

Comment: Using the `oSettings` variable directly (`oSettings.nTable.getAttribute('id')`) is [discouraged](https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Settings), as it's contents are private to the API and might change between versions without warning. Use `var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );` then access the table's id with `var tableId = api.table().node().id;`

Answer (score 8):

you can do something like this:
add a parameter to the configuration:

```
var oTable = $('#productTable').dataTable({
        "applyFilter":true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "sClass": "my_class", 
            "aTargets": [4]
            }],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $("td.my_class").editable(function(value, settings) 
            { 
                return(value);
            }, 
            {
                indicator : 'Save...',
                tooltip   : 'Click to Edit...'
            }
            );
        }
    });
```

and then, verify if your filter is active:

```
//Filter Function in Stock 
//$('#productTable').
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if(oSettings.applyFilter)
    {
        var checked = $('#instock').is(':checked');
        var qntStock = 1; 
        var stockCol = 3; 

        if (!checked) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checked && aData[stockCol] > qntStock) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried, but how about something like this ?

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        if ( oSettings.nTable == document.getElementById( 'productTable' )){
            var checked = $('#instock').is(':checked');
            var qntStock = 1; 
            var stockCol = 3; 

            if (!checked) {
                return true;
            }
            if (checked && aData[stockCol] > qntStock) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
}
);
```

the idea came from this thread : [2 datatables & 2 filters on the same page](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/5939/2-datatables-2-filters-on-the-same-page/p1)

---

You can also try out **my** [yadcf plugin for datatable](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) , here its [showcase url](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/), its has 9 different types of filters + additional API functions that can help you load table pre filtered or add single filter for filtering multiple table and many other cool stuff..

Answer (score 3):

It turns out filtering is global and indeed you have to filter the table element... it's quite disappointing.

Comment: Filtering is global, but you could get around it using ServerSideProcessing. If you use C#, PHP, or w/e language, you can pass the filter parameters through the ajax call and return the already filtered data. I have done that plenty of times, and it is much faster than the regular filtering (on big rows that is).

Comment: did you looked at my answer? and the link i gave... ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what we do:

```
            var temporarilySetFilterFunctions = $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering;
            $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering = [function (settings, data, index) {
                // our filter function
            } ];

            this._table.dataTable().fnDraw(); // filter!

            $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering = temporarilySetFilterFunctions;
```

Basically store the existing filters in a TEMP variable and then revert it after we are done.  Weird design descion on Allan's part to implement it like this. Ugly hack, but it works.

Comment: I think this solution more elegant from accepted answer. You can use this part of code in dynamically created tables.

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help in applying filter to data table.
http://live.datatables.net/oyinin/3/edit#javascript,html

I have used it like this:

```
  drawTable = function (tableId, url,    stateEngineURL) {
        resUrl = url;
        sUrl = stateEngineURL;
        oTable = $('#' + tableId).dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "bProcessing" : false,
            "bServerSide" : false,
            "sScrollY" : "150px",
            "bPaginate" : true,
            "bDeferRender" : true,
            "bScrollInfinite" : true,
            "bSortCellsTop" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : url,
            "aoColumns" : [
                {
                    "mDataProp" : "clusterName"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp" : "type"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp" : "actions",
                    "bSortable": false
                }
            ],
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({"name" : "REQUESTTYPE", "value" : "getCredentialResrcURL" });
                $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                    fnCallback(json);
                });
            },
            "fnRowCallback" : function (nRow, aData) {
                onRowCallBack(nRow, aData);
            }
        });
        oTable.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
                function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                   if(aData.type=='OSS 5.x'){
                       return false;
                   }
                }
            );
        oTable.fnDraw();
```