# Datatables - filter applied to just some tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In datatables, there's this filtering function

`$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex)`

that filters all tables.

I have two tables, and I need the filter to be applied to just one of the tables.

How do I let Datatables know that I just want to filter `table1` and leave `table2` as it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer elsewhere that helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11545376/4896102

Just added this inside the function

```
//array with the tables IDs you want the filtering function to ignore
var allowFilter = ['yourTableId1', 'youTableId2'];

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) 
{
    // check if current table is part of the allow list
    if ($.inArray(oSettings.nTable.getAttribute('id'), allowFilter ) == -1 )
    {
       // if not table should be ignored
       return true;
    }
    //rest of the code
    return false;
});
```

This one worked for me, and it has the advantage you can use an array so you can ignore multiple tables when filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this snippet from the DataTables creator.

https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/16623/using-fn-datatableext-afnfiltering-push-to-filter-tables

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(settings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        if (settings.nTable.id === 'myTableId') {
            // filter example
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
);
```

You can check for the `id` of the table you want to filter. It's not an official solution, but it works.

Comment: It looks like it might work, with a few tweaks.

I found this answer to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11545376/4896102

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataTables `.search()` and `.draw()` methods of the API. See the [online documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29)

```
var dt1 = $('#table1').DataTable();
dt1.search('search text').draw();
```

Also see working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w4amm0q/1/)

As an addendum, I just want to mention that in the 1.10+ DataTables, there are two ways to initialize the table: `.dataTable()` and `.DataTable()`. The second one returns the new API, which is what I used above. If you use the first one, you can still retrieve the new API using `$( selector ).dataTable().api()`, as documented in the [online documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/)