# jQuery.fn.dataTableExt bind to specific table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using the following to implement the custom search and filter on datatables.

```
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    ....
```

Now everything was fine and dandy, untill I had to implement multiple instances of datatables on the same page. So my question is how do I bind the above search and filter logic to a specific datatable?

PS: *I know that the code is for legacy version. But that is a non issue for me atm.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I have researched further, and I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447934/how-to-apply-filter-to-specific-datatable)
. Maybe this question is a duplicate.

So for future googlers,

**Actually the filters are global and you cannot apply them to a specific datatable. But inside the filter you can always check the current table id and proceed based on that info.**